# Can't import collections because of missing <collection.py>

Tags: python, compilation, arm, python-import

I spent a few days to make python run on an arm board. Then I succeed to install Django on it, too. But when I used django-admin.py to start a project, error came out:

```
[root@FriendlyARM /]# django-admin.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/django-admin.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.core import management
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import collections
ImportError: No module named collections
```

So it's clear that I don't have collections.py in my /usr/lib/python2.5/. Fortunately I have collections.py on my PC, which belongs to python2.7.

Now the problem is, can I just copy that collections.py into my arm board? Or should I do something else like modifying my arm-linux Makefile to make sure collections.py will appear in the arm-linux version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No; copying over `collections.py` may work, but is likely only the tip of the iceberg.

Django 1.5 requires Python 2.6 or newer. Do not try to run in on Python 2.5. You could *downgrade* to Django 1.4 instead, which does support Python 2.5.