# Unable to install dependencies for a django project with a virt env

Tags: python, django, macos, python-2.7

I have trouble installing a dependency for a django project:

```
(my_project123_env)$ python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
  File "/Users/alex/.virtualenvs/my_project123_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import collections
ImportError: No module named collections

(my_project123_env)silveranbook:my_project123 alex$ pip install collections
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/alex/.virtualenvs/my_project123_env/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "/Users/alex/.virtualenvs/my_project123_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from __future__ import absolute_import
ImportError: No module named __future__

(my_project123_env)silveranbook:my_project123 alex$ pip install __future__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/alex/.virtualenvs/my_project123_env/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "/Users/alex/.virtualenvs/my_project123_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from __future__ import absolute_import
ImportError: No module named __future__

(my_project123_env)silveranbook:my_project123 alex$ pip install future
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/alex/.virtualenvs/my_project123_env/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "/Users/alex/.virtualenvs/my_project123_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from __future__ import absolute_import
ImportError: No module named __future__
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: What happens, when you do `python -c 'import collections'`?

Comment: Have you looked at this? Sound like an issue with your Python install that has nothing to do with Django or Virtualenv http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18107198/

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp as it should, which means your *virtualenv* seems ok (i.e. python properly imports the `collections` module and then exits). You might try running with `python -v` and check the import trace.

Comment: Something's busted about your Python install, collections is part of the standard library. Looks like you're using OS X... you didn't just upgrade to Yosemite, did you?

Comment: May be, this answer help


  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17836185/cant-import-collections-because-of-missing-collection-py